# how to use the steady state probability to select a state in each iteration of the python code?

Tags: python

I have an ergodic markov chain whit three states. I calculated the steady state probability. 
the state present the input of my problem .
I want to solve my problem for n iteration which in each one we select the input based on the calculated steady state probability.
In the words, this is same a having three options with specific probability. and we want to select one of them randomly in each iteration.

Do you have any suggestion ??

Best, 
Aissan

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you have a vector of probabilities (instead of just 3) and also that your initial state is the first one.

```
import random

def markov(probs, iter):

  # normalize the probabilities
  total = sum(probs)
  probs = map(lambda e: float(e)/total, probs)

  # determine the number of states
  n = len(probs)

  # Set the initial state
  s = 0

  for i in xrange(iter):

    thresh = random.random()
    buildup = 0

    # When the sum of our probability vector is greater than `thresh`
    # we've found the next state
    for j in xrange(n):

      buildup += probs[j]
      if buildup >= thresh:
        break

    # Set the new state
    s = j

  return s
```

And thus

```
>>> markov([1,1,1], 100)
2
>>> markov([1,1,1], 100)
1
```

But this only returns the last state. It's easy to fix this with a neat trick, though. Let's turn this into a generator. We literally just need one more line, `yield s`.

```
def markov(probs, iter):
  # ...
  for i in xrange(iter):

    # Yield the current state
    yield s

    # ...
    for j in xrange(n):
      # ...
```

Now when we call `markov` we don't get an immediate response.

```
>>> g = markov([1,1,1], 100)
>>> g
<generator object markov at 0x10fce3280>
```

Instead we get a `generator object` which is kind of like a "frozen" loop. You can step it once with `next`

```
>>> g.next()
1
>>> g.next()
1
>>> g.next()
2
```

Or even unwind the whole thing with `list`

```
>>> list(markov([1,1,1], 100))
[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```